# Disable mouse hover on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have box which flips on hover. You can check here. 
http://rehabhousedeals.com/shortcode/

I have add red icon on top right corner on other side of box. 
I want as user will click on this icon box should flip back. 
Actually this is for mobile view. User should be able to flip back on front side by clicking this icon. 
Here are container class with hover effect in my css.

```
.card-container:not(.manual-flip):hover .card,
.card-container.hover.manual-flip .card{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
-moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
 -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}


.card-container.static:hover .card,
.card-container.static.hover .card {
    -webkit-transform: none;
-moz-transform: none;
 -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
```

Kindly help me get this.

Comment: check this website: https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly I may have a solution. I'm not sure if this can be done in css alone, but in JavaScript you can simply add a class on hover and remove it when the icon is clicked

something like this

```
 box.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
   this.classList.add('boxHover');
 });
```

and remove it when the icon is clicked

```
icon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.classList.remove('boxHover');
});
```

Here is an example 
https://jsfiddle.net/vqk8Ld46/

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Can you help me get by using my css classes. I have paste my css above.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS only solution - you can use a checkbox, and flip/unflip using the :checked pseudo-selector and the sibling selector. To control the checkbox from the card, you can use `<label>` tags with the `for` attribute:

```css
.front,
.back {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.front {
  background: red;
}

.back {
  background: blue;
}

.flip-container {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-control {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.flip-control:checked + .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}

.flip-control, .flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
  <input id="flipControl" class="flip-control" type="checkbox" />

  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <label for="flipControl" class="push-control-label"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148752.png" width="30px" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-right:-10px; margin-top:-10px;"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <label for="flipControl" class="push-control-label"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/148/148752.png" width="30px" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-right:-10px; margin-top:-10px;"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```